# How does water regulate temperature?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, water, geophysics

I've always realised that areas in close proximity to the ocean experience moderate temperature changes. I don't understand how water moderates this temperature. I suspect that it has something to do with water's specific heat capacity in contrast to the specific heat capacity of land. How does this work?

Comment: https://byjus.com/question-answer/why-do-coastal-regions-experience-moderate-climate/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to the [Earth Science site](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You are right. a body of water can soak up a remarkably large amount of heat energy and store it as "internal heat" whenever the air temperature is greater than the water temperature- and then when the reverse is true, it releases that stored heat to the air. This effect prevents things from getting too hot during the day and too cold at night.

So to help even out the temperature of the inside of a greenhouse full of sensitive plants, you can put some 55 gallon drums full of water inside it. they will soak up heat during the day and release it during the night.

Answer (score 1):

Cooling effect when sun is heating at high power or some hot air tries to enter the coast: Evaporative cooling.

Warming effect against cold air trying to enter the shore: The energy stored by evaporative cooling is released when water condenses.

One cubic meter of water has about the same heat capacity as one cubic meter of rock.